# Remote validation, No URL for remote validation could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2, remote-validation

Whatever tutorial or sample I use I get the exact same message over and over :

[image]

My Model :

```
public class Login
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Remote("CheckUserName", "Index", ErrorMessage = "Username already exists")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller :

```
[HttpPost][HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CheckUserName(string userName)
    {
        var repository = new List<Login>
                         {
                             new Login { UserName = "Gareth" },
                             new Login { UserName = "Lionel" }
                         };

        var exists = repository.Exists(x => x.UserName.Equals(userName));

        return exists ? Json(true) : Json($"Username already exists!");
    }
```

My View :

```
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Save" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"> </label>
        <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"> </span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save " class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

What did I forget or do wrong?

Using ASP .NET Core 2.2 MVC project.

Comment: What's the name of your controller class?

Comment: @ESG CheckUserName with returnType JsonResult

Comment: @user11208424 this is the validation method, ESG is asking about the class, e.g. the controller. (that should inherit from Controller)

Comment: Ah its just the HomeController

Comment: I do exactly what I find in the samples and even this sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0  But I keep getting the "No URL error message"....

Comment: @user11208424 try this if Home is controller:
`[Remote("CheckUserName", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Username already exists")]`

See default constructor of Remote [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_RemoteAttribute__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: @Dave Lel that was it, thx everyone!